# how to make an if-else in csh script

Tags: scripting, csh

I'm trying to make an if-else in csh script but it is not working:

do you know why this is not working?

```
if($2 == "rx" && $3 == "2") then
  setenv project_name       "mipi_2_rx_core_ns"
  setenv synth_logfile_name "mipi_2_rx_core_ns_syn"
  echo "RX 2 lanes"
  endif
  else if ($2 == "rx" && $3 == "4")
    setenv project_name       "mipi_4_tx_core_ns"
    setenv synth_logfile_name "mipi_4_tx_core_ns_syn"
    echo "RX 4 lanes"
endif
  else if ($2 == "plldig")
    setenv project_name       "dphyplldig"
    setenv synth_logfile_name "dphyplldig_syn"
  endif  
  else
    echo "No options specified"

endif
```

Comment: What is not working ? Please be specific about the issue. What line is failing or condition not working.

Comment: I just can enter in the first condition "rx 2", and not in the rest

Comment: endif are not correct. It should be if ... else ... endif  that is one block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the if else placement. You are missing then after ifs

```
#!/bin/csh

if ($2 == "rx" && $3 == "2") then
    setenv project_name       "mipi_2_rx_core_ns"
    setenv synth_logfile_name "mipi_2_rx_core_ns_syn"
    echo "RX 2 lanes"
else if ($2 == "rx" && $3 == "4") then
    setenv project_name       "mipi_4_tx_core_ns"
    setenv synth_logfile_name "mipi_4_tx_core_ns_syn"
    echo "RX 4 lanes"
else if ($2 == "plldig") then
    setenv project_name       "dphyplldig"
    setenv synth_logfile_name "dphyplldig_syn"
else
    echo "No options specified"
endif
```